# Blas GEMM launch failed [Tensorflow-GPU]

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train LSTM network for sequence to sequence task using tensorflow-gpu and no other library like keras on top of it. Whenever begin the training process i get this annoying error.

Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(128, 532), b.shape=(532, 1024), m=128, n=1024, k=532
     [[{{node rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](rnn/while/gru_cell/concat, rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter)]]
     [[{{node decode/decoder/while/Switch_6/_83}} = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1731_decode/decoder/while/Switch_6", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I googled up for solution and found that there might be other python process running in background but running command nvidia-smi provides no sign of it.